# Kafka Streams memory allocation issues with RocksDB

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I am trying to make a simple Kafka Stream application (v2.3.1 initially it was 2.3.0) which gathers statistics on specified time intervals (e.g. per minute namely tumbling windows).
Therefore I follow a textbook implementation like the one below

```
events
  .groupByKey()
  .windowedBy(
    TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(1).grace(Duration.ZERO))
    aggregate(...),Materialized.as("agg-metric")).withRetention(Duration.ofMinutes(5))

  .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowClose(BufferConfig.unbounded()))
  .toStream((key, value) -> key.key())
```

Everything seems to works normally except that my memory footprint is constantly growing. I can see that my heap memory is stable so I assume that the issue is related with RocksDB instances created.

I have 10 partitions and since each window  (with a default of 3 segments per partition), creates 3 segments, I expect in total to have 30 instances of RocksDB. Since the default configuration values for RocksDB are rather large for my app I choose to 
change the default configuration for RocksDB, and implement RocksDBConfigSetter according to code below essentially 
trying to impose a limit on off-heap memory consumption.

```
private static final long BLOCK_CACHE_SIZE = 8 * 1024 * 1024L;
private static final long BLOCK_SIZE = 4096L;
private static final long WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 2 * 1024 * 1024L;
private static final int MAX_WRITE_BUFFERS = 2;

private org.rocksdb.Cache cache = new org.rocksdb.LRUCache(BLOCK_CACHE_SIZE); // 8MB
private org.rocksdb.Filter filter = new org.rocksdb.BloomFilter();

@Override
public void setConfig(final String storeName, final Options options, final Map<String, Object> configs) {
     BlockBasedTableConfig tableConfig = new org.rocksdb.BlockBasedTableConfig();
    tableConfig.setBlockCache(cache) // 8 MB
    tableConfig.setBlockSize(BLOCK_SIZE); // 4 KB
    tableConfig.setCacheIndexAndFilterBlocks(true);;
    tableConfig.setPinTopLevelIndexAndFilter(true);

    tableConfig.setFilter(new org.rocksdb.BloomFilter())
    options.setMaxWriteBufferNumber(MAX_WRITE_BUFFERS); // 2 memtables
    options.setWriteBufferSize(WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE);  // 2 MB
    options.setInfoLogLevel(InfoLogLevel.INFO_LEVEL);

    options.setTableFormatConfig(tableConfig);
}
```

Based on the configuration values above and https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/sizing.html I expect that the total memory allocated to RocksDB would be

```
 (write_buffer_size_mb * write_buffer_count) + block_cache_size_mb => 2*2 + 8 => 12MB
```

Therefore for 30 instances the total allocated off-heap memory would account to 12 * 30 = **360 MB**.

When I try to run this app on a VM with 2G memory I assign 512MB for the heap of the kafka streams app,
so based on my logic/understanding the total memory allocated should plateau at a value lower than 1 GB (512 + 360).

Unfortunately this does not seem to be the case since my memory does not stop to grow, albeit slowly after a point, but steadily almost ~2% per day and it is unavoidable to consume all VM memory at some point and finally kill the process.
The more concerning fact is that I never witness any release of the off-heap memory, even when my traffic is getting very low.

As a result, I am wondering what am I doing wrong in such a simple and common use-case.
Am I missing something while calculating memory consumption for my app ? 
Is it possible to limit my memory consumption on my VM and what settings do I need to change on my configuration to limit memory allocation for Kafka stream app and RocksDB instances ?

Comment: Maybe you are hitting: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8637 ?

Comment: Hi Matthias thanks for the response, I spotted the issue and did the upgrade to kafka-streams 2.3.1 but it did not solve the problem (I 'll edit the initial post for the version)

Comment: @ypanag did you manage to resolve/understand what's happening there? Also, you might like to consider using a different memory allocator for solving the part about "no release of off-heap memory" you can read more about it here: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html#rocksdb

Comment: Hi @omer, thanks for the pointers but unfortunately I can't help, it has been a long time since we faced this issue and codebase changed drastically since then

Comment: @ypanag but did you manage to solve the issue?

Comment: No, I cannot remember solving it, we probably chose another alternative path at that time